# How to convert unknown type to string in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm dealing with an interface from an external piece of code. Boiled down to the minimum it looks like this:

```
interface Input {
    details?: unknown;
}
```

Now I need to map this object into different object with type:

```
interface Output {
    message?: string;
}
```

So `unknown` must be cast to a `string`. My initial approach was simply calling `input.details.toString()`, but `toString` is not available because `unknown` can also be `null` or `undefined`.

How do I transform `Input` to `Output`?

Comment: When an interface defines a type as `unknown` it means that you are not allowed to do anything with that data other than hold on to the reference. If this external code expects you to do anything with this data (other than maybe forward it back to them) then the type should not have been marked `unknown`. It should have been at least `any` if a more precise type is not possible.

Comment: @ccarton To my knowledge unknown is just a type-safe alternative to any. So why would any be better in your opinion?

Comment: `unknown` is "type-safe" because you are not allowed to do anything with the data. If they expect you to actually do something with the data then the type should reflect whatever it is they expect you to do with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To cast `unknown` to `string` you can use a [`typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards). The type of the ternary expression below will be inferred as `string | undefined`:

```
const output: Output = {
    message: typeof input.details === 'string'
        ? input.details
        : undefined,
};
```

Comment: How do you know `input.details` is only ever either a `string` or `undefined`?

Comment: @AriOhsie We _don't_ know, it can be anything, but if it _is_ a string, then we return it. If not, we return `undefined`. That way the result is always either `string` or `undefined`.

Comment: How would you do this with a desired output type of Array<String>?

Comment: @SpyderScript First check if the value is an array using `Array.isArray()` and if so, map each of the items to `string | undefined` like above so you end up with `Array<string | undefined> | undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution given, the value will only be `undefined` because `typeof input.details` is never equals to `string` as this is given that `typeof input.details` is `unknown`.


One workaround is that you can use

```
const output: Output = {
    message: input.details as string
}
```

Another workaround is that you can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` as given below.

```
const output: Output = {
    message: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input.details))
}
```

Please comment if anything is wrong or approve if it's useful. Thanks.